# How to parse xml tags with multiple xmlns attribute?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a xml value. I Am try to parse this, but result is null
My Xml

```
<DataPDU xmlns="urn:cma:stp:xsd:stp.1.0">
    <Body>
        <AppHdr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01">
            <Fr>
            <FIId>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <ClrSysMmbId>
                        <MmbId>4588745121</MmbId>
                    </ClrSysMmbId>
                </FinInstnId>
            </FIId>
        </Fr>
        <To>
            <FIId>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <ClrSysMmbId>
                        <MmbId>3501548751245701797</MmbId>
                    </ClrSysMmbId>
                </FinInstnId>
            </FIId>
        </To>
        <BizMsgIdr>Pac.Convert</BizMsgIdr>
        <MsgDefIdr>Pac.Convert.2019</MsgDefIdr>
        <BizSvc>Line</BizSvc>
        <CreDt>2019-06-07T17:06:35.38Z</CreDt>
        </AppHdr>
</Body>
</DataPDU>
```

My query to parse work good without attribute but with attribute returned null
My query:

```
 Select 

    x.XmlCol.value(N'(./Fr/FIId/FinInstnId/ClrSysMmbId/MmbId)[1]','nvarchar(200)') as FR_MmbId, --Идентификация устанавливается со стороны отправителя
    x.XmlCol.value(N'(./To/FIId/FinInstnId/ClrSysMmbId/MmbId)[1]','nvarchar(200)') as TO_MmbId,
    x.XmlCol.value(N'(./BizMsgIdr)[1]','nvarchar(200)') as BizMsgIdr
    from @Xml.nodes(N'/DataPDU/Body/AppHdr') x(XmlCol)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two namespaces involved. Both are without a prefix, hence showing up as the *default namespace*. All values are living within the *inner default namespace*. Therefore, to keep it simple, I suggest to use a prefix for the outer. This allows you to address all inner elements without a prefix:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01'
                           ,'urn:cma:stp:xsd:stp.1.0' AS ns)
SELECT AppHdr.value(N'(Fr/FIId/FinInstnId/ClrSysMmbId/MmbId/text())[1]','nvarchar(200)') as FR_MmbId
      ,AppHdr.value(N'(To/FIId/FinInstnId/ClrSysMmbId/MmbId/text())[1]','nvarchar(200)') as TO_MmbId
      ,AppHdr.value(N'(BizMsgIdr/text())[1]','nvarchar(200)') as BizMsgIdr
FROM @Xml.nodes(N'/ns:DataPDU/ns:Body/AppHdr') A(AppHdr);
```

Furthermore, you might omit the outer namespace and use wildcard:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01')
SELECT AppHdr.value(N'(Fr/FIId/FinInstnId/ClrSysMmbId/MmbId/text())[1]','nvarchar(200)') as FR_MmbId
      ,AppHdr.value(N'(To/FIId/FinInstnId/ClrSysMmbId/MmbId/text())[1]','nvarchar(200)') as TO_MmbId
      ,AppHdr.value(N'(BizMsgIdr/text())[1]','nvarchar(200)') as BizMsgIdr
FROM @Xml.nodes(N'/*:DataPDU/*:Body/AppHdr') A(AppHdr);
```

And the *deep search* with a doubled slash at the beginning would work too (as long as there is only one `<AppHdr>` element in your XML.

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01')
SELECT AppHdr.value(N'(Fr/FIId/FinInstnId/ClrSysMmbId/MmbId/text())[1]','nvarchar(200)') as FR_MmbId
      ,AppHdr.value(N'(To/FIId/FinInstnId/ClrSysMmbId/MmbId/text())[1]','nvarchar(200)') as TO_MmbId
      ,AppHdr.value(N'(BizMsgIdr/text())[1]','nvarchar(200)') as BizMsgIdr
FROM @Xml.nodes(N'//AppHdr') A(AppHdr);
```

Just for fun: This works too (with the given XML, this is **not recommended**) :

```
SELECT @xml.value(N'(//*:Fr//*:MmbId/text())[1]','nvarchar(200)') as FR_MmbId
      ,@xml.value(N'(//*:To//*:MmbId/text())[1]','nvarchar(200)') as TO_MmbId
      ,@xml.value(N'(//*:BizMsgIdr/text())[1]','nvarchar(200)') as BizMsgIdr
```

And even this works (with the given XML, this is **not recommended**) :-)

```
SELECT @xml.value(N'(//*:Fr)[1]','nvarchar(200)') as FR_MmbId
      ,@xml.value(N'(//*:To)[1]','nvarchar(200)') as TO_MmbId
      ,@xml.value(N'(//*:BizMsgIdr)[1]','nvarchar(200)') as BizMsgIdr
```

The general advise is: Be as specific as possible. This helps to avoid name clashes and is better in performance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle XMLNAMESPACES (xmlns) in different nodes to get your desired output. Try as below-

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
            'urn:cma:stp:xsd:stp.1.0' AS N1,
            'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01' AS N2,
            DEFAULT 'urn:cma:stp:xsd:stp.1.0'
)

Select 
x.XmlCol.value(N'(./N2:Fr/N2:FIId/N2:FinInstnId/N2:ClrSysMmbId/N2:MmbId)[1]','nvarchar(200)') as FR_MmbId, --Идентификация устанавливается со стороны отправителя
x.XmlCol.value(N'(./N2:To/N2:FIId/N2:FinInstnId/N2:ClrSysMmbId/N2:MmbId)[1]','nvarchar(200)') as TO_MmbId,
x.XmlCol.value(N'(./N2:BizMsgIdr)[1]','nvarchar(200)') as BizMsgIdr
from @Xml.nodes(N'/N1:DataPDU/Body/N2:AppHdr') x(XmlCol)
```